# What are the steps to uploading files to mongodb and get a url path to storage

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

How to **upload files** like *pdf* or *text* directly to mongoose and get a **url path** to db storage to display it

Comment: You can store files in MongoDB database collections using GridFS. GridFS stores the data within the database - so there is no idea about URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the database directly [`multer-gridfs-storage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-gridfs-storage) comes close to what you are looking for.